# Why does this string.punctuation code not work for stripping punctuation?

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I am confused why this code doesn't work the way I want. I am reading in a txt file and printing each item (comma separated) onto a new line. Each item is surrounded with "" and also contains punctuation. I am trying to remove this punctuation. I am familiar with string.punctuation and have it working on a test in my example, but it fails on the items I am looping through, see below:

```
def read_word_lists(path):
    import string
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines[0].split(','):
            line = str(line)
            line = line.strip().lower()
            print(''.join(word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in line))
            print(line)
            print(''.join(word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in '"why, does this work?! and not above?"'))

                
read_word_lists('file.txt')
```

The result is this:

```
trying to strip punctuation:  “you never”
originial:  “you never”
test:  why does this work and not above
trying to strip punctuation:  “you always
originial:  “you always"
test:  why does this work and not above
trying to strip punctuation:  ” “your problem is”
originial:  ” “your problem is”
test:  why does this work and not above
trying to strip punctuation:  “the trouble with you is”
originial:  “the trouble with you is”
test:  why does this work and not above
```

Any thoughts why the 'trying to strip punctuation' output is not working?

#### Edit

The original file looks like this, if useful:

`"YOU NEVER”, “YOU ALWAYS", ” “YOUR PROBLEM IS”, “THE TROUBLE WITH YOU IS”`

Comment: Possible that `“` is not punctuation but `"` is.

Comment: Comfirmed the docs. Only ASCII punctuation characters are part of `string.punctuation`, but your text contains unicode `”`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to strip unicode punctuation while `string.punctuation` only includes ascii punctuation.

Instead of using `string.punctuation`, you can use the code below to generate a string contains all of the Unicode punctuation characters:

```
import unicodedata
import sys

punctuation = "".join((chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')))
```

Good Luck!